# Как я могу передать значение переменной в событие?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть событие клика. По нажатии на кнопку, мне необходимо проверить нажата ли кнопка с верным ответом или нет. Эту проверку я вижу следующим образом: я передаю правильный ответ в эвент и сравниваю контекст нажатой кнопки с правильным ответом и в зависимости от результата выполняю какое-то действие. Но я не совсем понимаю как правильно передать данные в событие.

UPD: Пока что придумал только невероятно тупой костыль: создать скрытый лейбл в котором будет записано значение правильного ответа и сравнивать с ним.

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял, то у вас несколько кнопок с разными вариантами ответа и один евент который обрабатывает все кнопки. В таком случае вам достаточно проверить, что sender равен кнопке с правильным ответом.

Comment: зачем заводить контрол, если от него требуется только хранить значение? Просто создайте поле класса нужного типа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не такой уж и тупой у вас костыль. Просто, когда отображаете вопрос с ответами - кэшируйте, а при срабатывании события проверяйте на совпадение. А что именно кэшировать - это уже на вкус и цвет.
Или как вам подсказали в комментарии - запоминайте ссылку на кнопку с правильным ответом, или запоминайте сам правильный ответ или какой-то его идентификатор.